# Redirect logged in users to a "you don't have permission" error page in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

When a user is logged in and try to access a particular action which he’s not authorized to view, user is redirected to '/' (even you can get a loop behaviour in certain circumstances).
I've searched for solutions to this issue, but I didn't find anything.

I've written some lines in app_controller.php to redirect logged in users to an error page ("you have no permission to access...") but I'm not sure if I'm messing up the code.

Could you advise me? Thank you.

In app_controller.php:

```
var $components = array('Auth');

function beforeFilter() {
    $allowedActions = array_map('strtolower', $this->Auth->allowedActions);
    if (!($this->Auth->allowedActions == array('*') || in_array($this->action, $allowedActions))) {
        $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = Router::url(array('controller' => 'page', 'action' => 'error'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use

```
$this->Auth->loginError = "LOGIN ERROR";
$this->Auth->authError = "AUTH ERROR";
```

in *app_controller.php* combined with `echo $session->flash('auth');`
in your *default.ctp* view.

Another way is using *Auth* component's `isAuthorized` method and redirect depending on its outcome.

Comment: I'm actually using loginError and authError, but I don't just need to show a message, I need user will be redirected if he isn't authorized.
On the other hand, I didn't know about isAuthorized method and it works great replacing my $allowedActions related code.